# Navbar using Bootstrap not EXPANDING

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello all I've looked everywhere and can't seem to find the answer. My navbar is not able to expand at all listed where projects is.
http://www.wonsahm.com

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

```
<link href="bootstrap.css" rel ="stylesheet">
<link href="bootstrap.js" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.js">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="../../dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="navbar.css" rel="stylesheet">


<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="../">About Me</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Projects <b class="caret"></b></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have Jquery included on the page. Use Google Chrome tools (F12) and read the console errors.

> Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery

This needs including before you include `bootstrap.min.js`. There might be more problems after this one is resolved but this will certainly help you make head way.

It also appears that `navbar.css` is missing.

Comment: Got it! I didn't Google tools can read errors like that. Thank you so much. I was missing the two headers

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>